# Need a consolidated object value out of the while loop

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to get the values from the database using servlet and it retrieving fine inside the while loop only i can accessing the values retrieved from the database but i need to consolidatre all values into a single object. here is my code,

```
String moduleId = request.getParameter("moduleId").trim();
String temp[] = moduleId.split("/");
for(String s:temp){
    String modId[]=s.split("/");
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection connection=DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    ps=connection.prepareStatement("select * from testcase_sahi where module_id=?");
    ps.setString(1,modId[0]);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(".............TC ID...."+rs.getString("testcase_id"));
        System.out.println(".............TC Name...."+rs.getString("testcase_name"));
        testCase=rs.getString("testcase_name");
        /*fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
          out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
          System.out.println("****"+out.TC_OBJECT);
          out.writeObject(testCase);

          out.close();*/
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What should the result be?

Comment: is your 'single object' maybe a list (java.util.List)?

Comment: thanks, result of the select statement is two or more values, and inside the while loop am going to serialize the whole result but what happening here is , while serializing the object it serialize only the last result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply store your data in a List...

```
String moduleId = request.getParameter("moduleId").trim();
String temp[] = moduleId.split("/");
for(String s:temp){
    String modId[]=s.split("/");
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection connection=DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    ps=connection.prepareStatement("select * from testcase_sahi where module_id=?");
    ps.setString(1,modId[0]);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();


    List temporaryList = new ArrayList();  //HERE

    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(".............TC ID...."+rs.getString("testcase_id"));
        System.out.println(".............TC Name...."+rs.getString("testcase_name"));
        testCase=rs.getString("testcase_name");

        temporaryList.add(testCase); //HERE

    }

    serializeData(temporaryList) //and HERE

}
```